# Creating a new Page of Posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to make a e-zine using wordpress, and have most of it done. The homepage displays a list of the "pieces" which are included in that edition of the e-zine. I would like to make it so that, when an edition expires (currently using Post Expirator plugin), a new page is created automatically resembling the front page in showing the index of that particular (now expired) edition.

I'm not very experienced using PHP, and still a newbie at wordpress. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: As far as I can understand, you are trying to create an archive of index pages. If so, check the PHP copy() function to save them with a different name.

Comment: Well, it is more like an archive of past issues, which are indeed similar to the index page. I'm looking at the copy() function right now... what you are suggesting is to copy the current index page when it expires and save it under some other name, right?

Comment: Yes. The reason is there is no WP function to do that, as far as I know. You would have to copy past index pages and save them with another name.

Comment: Ok, I think I can manage that. I'll try it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing, using the suggestions of Felipe as a starting point. There might be a less convulted way of doing this, but, as I said, I'm just a beginner, so this is what I came up with:

First, I created a volnum variable, which keeps track of the current volume number. Then, I cache the front page so that later I can save it as an independent html document: 
This is at the beginning of the index.php, before the get_header().

```
<?php $volnum; ?>
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

In the front page, I have an editorial and, next to it, I have the content index. I am saving the editorial tag's (which is always "voln" where 'n' is the volume number) volume number (maybe the foreach is not necessary since the editorial only has one tag)  :

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tags();
      foreach ($tags as $tag){
        $volnum = $tag->name;
      }
?>
```

Finally, at the end of the document, after the last html, I have added the following code:

```
<?php
    $handle = opendir("past_vol/");
    $numOfFiles = count($handle);
    $volExists = false;
    for($i=0;$i<=$numOfFiles;$i++){
        $name = readdir($handle);
        if($volnum.".html" == ($name)){
            $volExists = true;
            continue; 
        }
    }
    if($volExists == false){
        $cachefile = "past_vol/".$volnum.".html";
        $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w'); 
        fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
        fclose($fp);
    }
    closedir($handle);
    ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

"past_vol" is the directory where I am saving the past volume html files. So the directory is opened, the amount of files is counted, and a loop that goes through each file's name is started. If a file with the same name as $volnum, then $volExists is true. If at the end of the loop $volExists is false, then it saves the cached page.

Again, it could probably be optimized a whole lot, but for now this works!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this, you just have to get the expiration date and make a condition with it. You just need to have a basic php skills in order for you to do it. Heres the logic

```
  if($curdate > $expiration_date){ //you can change the condition into ">=" if you want to create a post on and after expiration date

      //sample wordpress wp_insert_post
      $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => 'My post',
        'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_category' => array(8,39)
      );

      // Insert the post into the database
      wp_insert_post( $my_post );

   }
```

for more info visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: Would I add this in my index page? Also, wouldn't this just create one page where all of the expired posts would go?